# using OSRM Routing in Openlayers 3 to draw polyines on the map along the direction of the map

Tags: routes, openlayers-3, polyline, osrm

I'd like to implement routing on my map using OSRM and Openlayers 3 but there don't seem to be any examples or tutorials anywhere.All the sample are to confusing

Sources refereed 1:http://workshop.pgrouting.org/chapters/ol3_client.html (in this sample i don't know from where to get the data to plot the polyline i will be getting the data as a json which contains array of object with latitude and longitude)

2:http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers don't know where to start with to accomplish it

3:OSRM Routing in Openlayers 3

i am able to draw a straight line but i wanted to draw different color lines along the direction of the map , i came to know for this i have to use a direction service can any body please point to some sample code or post any help will be thankful please say a way to accomplish it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start using an online service and if you feel comfortable with it go for devloping your own (if needed)

so lets assume you are going to use YOURS routing service. info and details [here](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/YOURS)

1. create a GET request 
   `http://www.yournavigation.org/api/1.0/gosmore.php?format=geojson&flat=52.215676&flon=5.963946&tlat=52.2573&tlon=6.1799&v=motorcar&fast=1&layer=mapnik`

just put the above url into a browser. It shall give you back a response containing the coordinates of the line you are looking for. To use it with in your own app you propably have to create a proxy servlet to avoid the cross domain scripting problem.

2. Parse the responce getted back. Note that the response is not a proper geojson (at least as ol3 may understand it) so you get the coordinates, create the geometry and reproject them to your projection
3. Finally display your route to your map and zoom to the extent of your route

here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/LmyLn7wu/) to see it in action. Note that I am using the responce of the above request as a json object within the code.

**UPDATE**

The same request for OSRM would be

`https://api-osrm-routed-production.tilestream.net/viaroute?instructions=true&alt=true&loc=52.215676,5.963946&loc=52.2573,6.1799`

This should return an encoded polyline. So you may decode your route using the `ol.format.Polyline` class. Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/bykc6sbu/)

Comment: thank you so much for the details steps when try to recreate the code from fiddle locally i ma getting the error has TypeError: map.getView(...).fit is not a function i have included only the ol.js in the script please say where i am going wrong
 

map.getView().fit(extentToZoom,map.getSize())

Comment: you propably use an older version of ol3. try to upgrade to the latest.

Comment: u r ossom and that was the mistake

Comment: can u please say where to look for the url to send in th  get request for map quest and OSRM

Comment: I hava added one more alternative using OSRM(update my answer). But you have to investigate and find out which services are available free and fit to your needs. I cannt help you more as I have no further experience with that. If you come up with something intersting let us know. Good luck

Comment: can u please have a look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34766232/how-to-place-markers-on-the-image-using-openlayer3

Comment: @pavlos I am using osrm's new API json response instead of your geojsonObject variable in your fiddle. But its not plotting the route on desired points. Can you guide about the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Consider this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jonataswalker/079xha47/) to start with:

```js
map.on('click', function(evt){
  utils.getNearest(evt.coordinate).then(function(coord_street){
    var last_point = points[points.length - 1];
    var points_length = points.push(coord_street);

    utils.createFeature(coord_street);

    if (points_length < 2) {
      msg_el.innerHTML = 'Click to add another point';
      return;
    }

    //get the route
    var point1 = last_point.join();
    var point2 = coord_street.join();

    fetch(url_osrm_route + point1 + ';' + point2).then(function(r) { 
      return r.json();
    }).then(function(json) {
      if(json.code !== 'Ok') {
        msg_el.innerHTML = 'No route found.';
        return;
      }
      msg_el.innerHTML = 'Route added';
      //points.length = 0;
      utils.createRoute(json.routes[0].geometry);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Jonatas, is something wrong with the OSRM ? I tried your fiddle like a week ago and it was working, but now it's not

Comment: @HichamZouarhi Checked it now and it's OK, just changed to OSM tiles.

Comment: Thanks a lot :D I changed the tiles to OSM too but it didn't work before

Comment: @HichamZouarhi - the fiddle is not working on my side... any help please?

Comment: @user2707590 See https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues/2875

Comment: @user2707590 I made a little workaround for offline routing with OL3, check here https://github.com/HichamZouarhi/offline-routing-OL3